# Regex extract full stop / period after time in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
00:02:44.372
```

I would like to regex just to extract the full stop / period only.

I have tried to use:

```
[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]
```

which selects the duration, but where do I go from here? As this is a script that will only be used once just for some maintenance I am not too worried about its efficiency and should be in javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by *"extract the full stop"*? What is the end result you want to achieve?

Comment: When you say "extract" you mean "remove the full stop and the digits after it", yes? I.e., you want to "extract" the hours:minutes:seconds? Whether or not I've guessed right, please edit your question to show the desired output.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not being clear I've working on this project and my brain is a bit fried but @Blender gave me the answer i needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `.split`:

```
> '00:02:44.372'.split(':')
["00", "02", "44.372"]
> '00:02:44.372'.split(':').slice(-1)
["44.372"]
> '00:02:44.372'.split(':').slice(-1)[0]
"44.372"
```

As for your regex, you need to add capturing groups:

```
> '00:02:44.372'.match(/^(\d+):(\d+):(\d+\.\d+)$/)
["00:02:44.372", "00", "02", "44.372"]
```

Comment: A simpler regular expression to use with match is `/[\d\.]+/g`. Also consider `'00:02:44.372'.split(':')[2]` => `'44.372'`.

Answer (score 0):

one alternative is to get the index of period first then use .substring() method to extract the string from index 0 to the index of period-1 and then the rest of the string, if you need assistance let me know. To find index you can use string.indexOf(regularEx)